# fopen() causing segmentation fault when called on an existing file

Tags: c

When I try to call fopen() in C, I get the segmentation fault only on calls with a file in the directory.  I'm working on a project that uses a fingerprint sensor, registers the fingerprint onto a file, then reads the file to compare to a fingerprint thats is being read in runtime.

Here's the gist of the code.

```
FILE * file;
// right_thumb.bin is located in the same directory as the file.
// right_thumb.bin is created using fwrite.
file = fopen("right_thumb.bin", "rb");
// program crashes right at the line above, with the segmentation fault error.
ABS_BIR * readImage;
fread(&readImage, sizeof(ABS_BIR), sizeof(&var), file);
// &var is a pointer to the fingerprint that was written
// ABS_BIR is the fingerprint data type
fclose(file);
```

The strange thing is, that the following works perfectly...

```
File * file;
file = fopen("right_thumb.bin", "w");
fwrite(&var, sizeof(ABS_BIR)/*size of the type the fingerprint is stored in*/
, sizeof(&var)/*8*/, file);
fclose(file);
file = fopen("right_thumb.bin", "rb");
fread(&readImage, sizeof(ABS_BIR), sizeof(&var), file);
```

what is strange is that I can freely open the same file created, but if I change the file to a different file created by an older instance of this file, I get the error.

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior somewhere else in your code.  Run it under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you find out where.

Comment: If it's crashing on a standard `fopen()` call then more than likely you've corrupted the stack prior to calling it.

Comment: Why are you so sure that's the `fopen`call crashing you program? You want to run your code using a debugger to exactly determine the line where the program crashes.

Answer (score 4):

it seems you have trouble understanding [`fread`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) [`fwrite`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) usage and pointer variable, and it has very little to do with your `fopen` call

- [`fread`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) won't allocate a buffer for you, you need to allocate it
- `readImage` is already a pointer ( *unallocated* ) when you are using it as an argument to [`fread`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread),  so its value could be anything,
  Addditionally you are passing `&readImage` which mean you will write to the address of the pointer. which could be valid, but I doubt that was your intention.
- `sizeof` return the size of the variable you pass as argument,for example in your case :
  `sizeof(&var)` returns the size of the address to `var` ( which is apparently `8` on your system )

I would recommend you use a debugger, which would provide you some insight on what is going on with your code.

My guess is that you should write the following :

```
File * file;
file = fopen("right_thumb.bin", "w");
fwrite(var, sizeof(ABS_BIR)/*size of the type the fingerprint is stored in*/
, 1/* corrected, only one buffer of ABS_BIR size to write*/, file);
fclose(file);

file = fopen("right_thumb.bin", "rb");
ABS_BIR * readImage=malloc(sizeof(ABS_BIR));
fread(readImage, sizeof(ABS_BIR), 1, file);
```

Note that I changed your instance of `sizeof(&var)` to `1` as you are reading and writing one buffer of size `sizeof(ABS_BIR)` to/from that file